# Google ecommerce with Google Analytic PHP API

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Is some way to upload transaction throw Google Analytic API? I can just get it. But I do not found any information how to send transaction to Google in Analytic API. Any ideas? Maybe Google API can just get the result, but do not send data to Analytic?

Comment: by the way, is there a way to download the transaction throw Google Analytic ecommerce API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Core Reporting API provides access to the tabular data in Google Analytics standard and custom reports. To access data, you create a query that specifies: the view (profile), the start and end dates, and the dimensions and metrics that make up the column headers in the table. This query is sent to the Core Reporting API and The Core Reporting API returns all the data in the form of a table.

Refer : - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide

Comment: So maybe you have any ideas how to send ecommerce transactions to google without any javascritp? just server to server?