# Server-server communication (sending) for Google Analytics ecommerce

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, e-commerce, google-analytics-api

I can use Google Analytics ecommerce on the client via a javascript script https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEcommerce, in other words it's client-server communication.

I have some financial data I receive through API from my customers and I want to send it to Google Analytics ecommerce using server-server communication, primarily, I want to **send** that data to Google Analytics ecommerce.

To say it simpler, when I inject a javascript file to a page, it uploads the information to Google Analytics ecommerce from the client (browser). But since I already have that information received from my customers through API and stored on my server, I want to upload it Google Analytics ecommerce by myself - from my server.

Can I do that? How? According to this [Google ecommerce with Google Analytic PHP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281749/google-ecommerce-with-google-analytic-php-api), it may not be possible.

Comment: Have you taken a look at using the [Data Import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191589?hl=en&ref_topic=6064627) functionality?

Comment: @Blexy, but it requires importing it manually, doesn't it? Whereas I need to do that automatically by API, of course.

Comment: You can do data imports via the api, but you can only add data to existing transactions, not create transactions from scratch (for that you would rather use the measurement protocol).

Comment: @EikePierstorff I need to create them from scratch, of course - I'm already given the data. `for that you would rather use the measurement protocol` - what part are you referring to?